# Usage onSnapshot within React's Context

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React app in which I use custom made Context to store the app's data. The Context component utilizes `onSnapshot` method used to get the data from the Firestore database. Furthermore `onSnapshot` method returns a function that is used to "unregister" the listener, which normally is called upon dismounting React's component.

How should the unregister function be called having the listener working inside of a Context? From what I understand the mounting of a Context is performed upon it's first usage via use-hook function, but then, as the Context object persistent during the app's session, the unmounting process is never called therefore making "unregistering" impossible. Is there any solution to the usage of a snapshot listener within a Context object?

Comment: When do you want it to unregister? If you want it to continue updating for the lifetime of the webpage, it's fine that the unregister function never gets called (you should still return it from your useEffect though). If you want to get the data just once and never update, perhaps use `getDoc` instead of `onSnapshot`

Comment: @NicholasTower I want to have the listeners being active during the app session, based on user's auth (which I can handle via [user] effect's argument). I think you've answered my question. Thanks

Comment: @Eric, Glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.